# Components per SmartTarget Experiment Variant?

Tags: smarttarget

I have the following SmartTarget (ST) Experiments questions (somewhat related to [SmartTarget Experiment Percentages?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/12341/46)).

**When I add Variants to "Content items displayed when the Experiment is triggered" can I add multiple items per variant?**

On my environment I see multiple items under Variants like below, but not separate *sets* of content.

Variants:

- Banner1
- Banner2
- Banner3

Does the region size affect variations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Component Presentation added is a Variant. So no, you cannot add multiple per Variant.

Region size does not affect an Experiment. It will always output a single Variant and it will always override any other Promotions in that region.

Comment: Okay. I'll use this for "promotion" and maybe container-based scenarios. Does it relate to the analytics, where the single Component Presentation has analytics tags?

Comment: It was designed to be a simple implementation, so having multiple CPs per Variant just wasn't considered.